# Compile error with pointer to template function in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to create a template class that stores a function pointer to a template function, but ran into a compile error in Visual Studio 2008.  I created a simplified test case for it(see below) which still fails to compile in VS2008, but appeared to compile successfully on the online Comeau and online GCC compilers I tried.

The error I'm seeing is:

```
error C2436: 'func' : member function or nested class in constructor initializer list
temp.cpp(21) : while compiling class template member function 'test_class<T>::test_class(T (__cdecl &))'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int (const int &)
1>        ]
```

The same test using a non-template function works.  Short of that, does anyone know a workaround for the issue, or if VS2008 is expecting some kind of different syntax for this?

Thanks,

Jerry

```
template<class T>
T template_function(const T& arg)
{
    return arg;
}

int non_template_function(const int& arg)
{
    return arg;
}

template<class T>
class test_class
{
public:
    test_class(const T& arg) : func(arg) {}
private:
    T func;
};

template<class T>
void create_class(const T& arg)
{
new test_class<T>(arg);
}

int main()
{
    create_class(&template_function<int>); //compile fails unless this is commented out
    create_class(&non_template_function);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the question, well written, nice minimal working example. Can't answer it authoritatively but __cdecl in the error message sets alarm bells ringing with regards to linkage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the "const T& arg" in test_class and create_class are your problem. Changing those to a simple "T arg" seems to smooth things out.

Comment: That's exactly it, thanks!  No idea why that fails with the template function and not the non-templated one, but with that change it works for both.

Comment: Ran into the same problem, and this answer solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Fix at two places;

```
T* func; //make this pointer type!
```

and,

```
 create_class(template_function<int>); //remove '&'
 create_class(non_template_function); //remove '&'
```

Done!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a compiler bug because it actually thinks that you are trying to invoke that function instead of initializing.

I don't have VS C++ compiler, but declaring `T` as a pointer may work around the problem:

```
template<class T>
class test_class
{
public:
    test_class(const T& arg) :
        func(&arg)
    {
    }

private:
    T *func;
};


template<class T>
void create_class(const T& arg)
{
    new test_class<T>(arg);
}

int main()
{
    create_class(template_function<int>); //compile fails unless this is commented out
    create_class(non_template_function);
}
```